# How to filter by a given phrase in a single column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is the sample data. Seems pretty basic but my internet searches have not yielded a clear answer. In this case, how would I create a new data frame where the areaname only has the phrase MSA at the end and not MicroSA or other possibilities.

```
  areaname <- c("Albany NY MSA", "Albany GA MSA", "Aberdeen SD MicroSA", "Reno NV MSA", "Fernley NV MicroSA", "Syracuse NY MSA")
  Employment <- c(100,104,108,112,116,88)

   testitem <- data.frame(areaname, Employment)
```

Comment: `subset(testitem, endsWith(areaname, "MSA"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use `stringi`:

```
library(dplyr)

testitem %>%
  filter(stringi::stri_endswith_fixed(areaname, "MSA"))
```

**Output**

```
         areaname Employment
1   Albany NY MSA        100
2   Albany GA MSA        104
3     Reno NV MSA        112
4 Syracuse NY MSA         88
```

Or you can use `grepl`:

```
library(dplyr)

testitem %>%
  filter(grepl("MSA$", areaname))
```

Or use `endsWith`:

```
testitem %>%
  filter(endsWith(areaname, "MSA"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
testitem %>%
  filter(stringr::str_ends(areaname, "MSA"))


         areaname Employment
1   Albany NY MSA        100
2   Albany GA MSA        104
3     Reno NV MSA        112
4 Syracuse NY MSA         88
```